# Eyes goes red when i do knuckle pushups. Is this normal?

Tags: push-ups

I don't do many pushups, For now, i simply do 15 knuckle pushups/day increasing 1/week. After I completed my push-ups, i look into the mirror, I see red eyes. is this normal?

Comment: No, that doesn't sound normal. Go see a doctor.

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER.**  This site is not intended to provide medical advice, and this answer should not be interpreted as the advice of a medical professional.  You are advised to seek medical attention from a licensed physician.

If the sclerae of the eyes appear red, this is due to the capillaries and blood vessels dilating in one or more of the associated tissues (conjunctiva, episclera, and sclera).  If this is a transient and short-lived phenomenon with no concomitant pain, change in vision (e.g. loss of visual acuity, peripheral vision, color perception, sudden floaters or bright flashes), or other sequelae such as evidence of infection (pus, discharge), it is likely to be harmless, but again, you are advised to consult an eye doctor.

The underlying physiological mechanism is that an increase in blood pressure can cause these capillaries and vessels to dilate.  This can be observed, for example, by standing on one's head.  The effect should be very brief and resolve rapidly.  However, if it lasts for more than a few minutes or is accompanied by pain, headache, shortness of breath, or nausea, that may be cause for concern.  Prolonged physical exertion for some individuals with high blood pressure could also cause this sign.  However, there are other common (and uncommon) disorders of the eye that can cause redness.

Ultimately, without knowing more about your medical history, let alone your level of physical fitness and your exercise plan, it is impossible to determine if this is something to be concerned about.  This is why, whenever embarking on new forms of exercise, it is important to consult your physician, and when experiencing unexpected medical signs or symptoms as a result of exercise, your physician should be the first person to hear about it.

Comment: Great answer, my only adjustment would be "licensed medical practitioner" (instead of "licensed physician") as nurse practitioners in my area (just as an example) are licensed and trained to be independent providers.